# Postgresql Select Constant

Tags: sql, postgresql

In Oracle I can select a constant value that will populate down the column like this:

```
Select 
     "constant" constantvalue,
     orders.name
from 
     orders
```

and it will yield:

```
ConstantValue     Name
  constant       sandwich
  constant        burger
```

For whatever reason, when I try to do this in postgres I receive this error.

```
ERROR:  column "Constant" does not exist
```

here is my code

```
    select
        date_trunc('day', measurement_date + (interval '1 day' * (6 - extract(dow from measurement_date)))) week,
        "AROutstanding" colname,
        round(avg(Total_Outstanding),0) numbah
    from
                (
                select
                    measurement_date,

                    sum(cast(sum_of_dollars as numeric)) Total_Outstanding
                from
                    stock_metrics
                where
                    invoice_status not in  ('F','Write off')
                group by
                    measurement_date
                ) tt
            group by
                week
```

Comment: Single quotes are the correct way to express a constant string value in SQL (and they work in any database).  I consider this a simple typographic error.

Answer (score 38):

Change your double quotes to single quotes.

So this:

```
Select 
     "constant" as constantvalue,
     orders.name
from 
     orders
```

Should be this:

```
Select 
     'constant' as constantvalue,
     orders.name
from 
     orders
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I thought I tried it but apparently not :)

Comment: It's always a pain moving from one DB to another. I went from MSSQL to MySQL and I'm googling for answers all the time!

Comment: You should be careful when "Omitting the AS Key Word" as noted in the manual https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html some of the keywords https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html could well interfere with the chosen column name.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone confused by [@Adrian Lynch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/121946/adrian-lynch)'s answer, I found out that doing

```
SELECT
    'constant' AS ConstantValue,
    orders.name
FROM
    orders
```

did the trick for me.

This could be used for numbers as follows: `1234 AS constantvalue`.

Comment: What part was confusing @RCRalph? The lack of `as`? I've added it to the answer.

Comment: @AdrianLynch yes that was it, thanks for editing